# Website url visit on tap (lua)?

Tags: android, lua

Is it possible to direct to a website on tap:

```
local sign = display.newText(  "Designed by AAA", 0, 0, helvetica, 20 )
sign:addEventListener ( "tap", url:"www.aaa.com" )
```

This is not working..help

Comment: Try explaining why it doesn't work and what else you have tried

Comment: sign:addEventListener ( "tap", "www.aaa.com" )

Comment: sign:addEventListener ( "tap", url="www.aaa.com" )

Comment: I think I m taking a wrong approach..plz help if u noe how to make it work...wht I want is to directly open the website on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. hope it works for u

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I m new 2 lua...plz suggest sumthn widout using intent
An easy way juz d way i hav given d eg

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```